# How wait until the env vars are loaded in Node.JS/TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Objective: to load slack credentials into env vars before starting the server.

I've got my `env.ts`:

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from "path";
import { loadAwsSecretToEnv } from "./awsSecretLoader";

const stage = process.env.NODE_ENV ?? "local";
dotenv.config();

if (process.env.SLACK_SECRET) {
  loadAwsSecretToEnv(process.env.SLACK_SECRET);
}
```

And my `index.ts` is:

```js
import "./config/env";
import logger from "./logger";
import { app } from "./slack";

// Start ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const port = (process.env.PORT || 8080) as number;
(async () => {
  await app.start(port);
  logger.info("⚡️ Slack is running on port %s!", port);
})();
```

Now the problem is `loadAwsSecretToEnv` is asynchronous (obviously) and by the time the server starts the credentials are not loaded into the env vars, thus the server fails to start.

My question is how to make sure that the env vars are loaded before starting the app.
I'm new to TS and not sure if the whole approach is flawed or if there's a solution for the above problem.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: If `loadAwsSecretToEnv` returns a promise, you can `await` it before you run `app.start` ?

Comment: So do all the work in `env.ts` in an exported function, so `index.ts` can decide when to call it and how to wait for the result.

Comment: That means I need to move the code next to `app` snippet, right? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: No, this is what functions are for! If you do everything 'outside' a function you just lose a lot of control.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. The code in `./slack` does a lot of stuff using env vars. That means I need to refactor the whole code as well. Is there a way to do something similar to what `dotenv.config()` does. I suspect it loads the env vars from the file in a synchronous way. No?

Answer (score 1):

Currently `env.ts` doesn't tell the outside world, when the loading has finished. This is what promises are for.

You need to:

1. Return a promise in `env.ts`, that resolves once the loading has finished
2. Await the promise in `index.ts`

`env.ts`:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from "path";
import { loadAwsSecretToEnv } from "./awsSecretLoader";

// Expose a function, that returns a promise
export default async function loadConfiguration() {
  const stage = process.env.NODE_ENV ?? "local";
  dotenv.config();

  if (process.env.SLACK_SECRET) {
    await loadAwsSecretToEnv(process.env.SLACK_SECRET); // propagate all inner promises by awaiting them
  }
}
```

`index.ts`:

```
import loadConfiguration from "./config/env"; // Get the load function
import logger from "./logger";
import { app } from "./slack";

// Start ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
(async () => {
  await loadConfiguration();

  // Now we're safe, since we have waited for the configuration to load

  const port = (process.env.PORT || 8080) as number;
  await app.start(port);
  logger.info("⚡️ Slack is running on port %s!", port);
})();
```

Comment: I don't think this is gonna help. AFAIK adding `await` doesn't guarantee the order of execution. In other words, where you wrote _Now we're safe_, we're not really safe.

Comment: If `loadAwsSecretToEnv` returns a promise, then `await` *guarantees*, that the promise has been resolved ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)). If not, then you need to improve `loadAwsSecretToEnv` to make callers aware of when it has finished; either by returning a promise or allowing a callback function as argument.

Comment: Right. My understanding was not correct. But still I'd like to know if there's a way to do it like how `dotenv.config()` does it.

Comment: As you stated previously, `loadAwsSecretToEnv` is *asynchronous*. This means, that when the function returns, you have no idea about when the asynchronous part of the function ends. As I said above, you have to rework the function to allow the caller to know, when the asynchronous part has ended, and there are two ways: Promises or callback function arguments.

Comment: Alternatively you can choose to make the `loadAwsSecretToEnv` *synchronous*. That means, that when the function returns, nothing else is going behind the scenes. I don't know the internals of the function, so I obviously cannot guide you further, but sometimes asynchronous functions have a synchronous variant as well, that you might make use of.

Comment: Obviously you need to consider the implications of choosing one over the other. There's a good reason for JavaScript to expose ways of working with asynchronous code, since it is single threaded, so long blocking/synchronous operations are costly